# Changing colour of one item in Cell Detail Text (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, sdk

I have the following code in my app which changes the cell details text items to blue.

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", 
                             info.area, info.addressOne];
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0x33/255.0 green:0               blue:0x99/255.0     alpha:1.0];
```

Is there anyway to change the colour of the two items here independently instead of both being blue ?

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UILabel can’t display multiple colors. You’ll need to set up a pair of labels manually and add them to the cell’s `contentView`. For laying them out, use NSString’s `-sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` method to get the width of the two strings and position/size the labels accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create your own cell instead of use the default style so you can have two different UILabels.  That way, you can have the color be different for the two UILabels.